# MPMoviePlayerController & .m3u8 playlist

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I would like to use a .m3u8 playlist containing remote mp4 files with MPMoviePlayerController, did you success with this ?

1. Does the .m3u8 must contain .ts file ?
   If not what is the purpose of .ts ?
2. Does next / previous buttons will be enable once the playlist be loaded ?
   If not, what is the purpose of these buttons ?
3. And last question, do you have a .m3u8 sample file with remote mp4 file to test ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Thierry

Answer (score 16):

Since you're talking about `.m3u8` and `.ts` files, can I assume you're interested in HTTP Live Streaming, as supported by iPhone OS 3.0 and Snow Leopard? There is more info about HTTP Live Streaming in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

1. In HTTP Live Streaming, the `.m3u8` file lists other files that are to be downloaded and played in order.  If the `.m3u8` file doesn't contain an `#EXT-X-ENDLIST` directive, then the client assumes the source is a live stream, and periodically re-fetches the `.m3u8` to find new media files to download.  The `.ts` files are MPEG-2 trasnsport stream files that contain muxed audio and video (despite the fact that the transport stream is part of the MPEG-2 spec, the contents should be H.264 and AAC, the audio and video codecs usually associated with MPEG-4).  You sometimes see other contents, like `.aac` for audio-only streams.  A server will segment a video stream into many `.ts` files, the `.m3u8` file will provide URLs for these `.ts` files, and a client will download and play the `.ts` files in order.  As an iPhone developer, all you have to do is provide the `.m3u8` URL to the `MPMoviePlayerController`, which will handle the rest.
2. Don't know about the prev/next buttons... don't seem like they'd make sense in a stream context, and I'm not sure whether the the `MPMoviePlayerController` even shows them.  You can use the `movieControlMode` property to set what controls are offered to the user.
3. Apple's [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-DontLinkElementID_15) provide links to some sample test pattern streams.