# mp4 vs m3u8 format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to play a video in iPhone, which has m3u8 format. The video's link is parsed from an XML (so i cannot change it). I'm trying to play it with MoviePlayerController (set it on fullscreen, controlStyle is fullscreen too, set the presentModalViewController to the MoviePlayerController). After pressing the play button, the movie has only sound for a few seconds, no video screen, and the app crashes.

In this XML I have a different videolink, which contains mp4 format. Playing the video in the same mode (with MoviePlayerController and the settings...), it works fine. So: do you have any ideas what the problem is? If there is any encoding problems of m3u8? If it can be changed and how?

Thank you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665151/mpmovieplayercontroller-m3u8-playlist is probably related to your question.  m3u8 is a playlist, not a video format.

Comment: @fvu you are basically correct but in fact m3u8 in this context is used for HTTP-video-streams consisting of H264 encoded video data  wrapped within transport stream (TS) chunks file format. We could debate for hours on the incorrect usage of MP4 as well as M3U(8) when it comes to describing file formats / codecs and transport mechanisms - though I feel that is a pointless endeavor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look the AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewController class from this very useful open source control released by Peter Steinberger
https://github.com/steipete/PSPushPopPressView
Thanks again Peter!