# Open movie stream in another view

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have in my app a tab view with many tabs, and in one of them I have a button that when is clicked, I want to show a movie stream in a view. I have this code:

```
NSString *moviePath = @"http://10.0.0.4/prog_index.m3u8";

theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:moviePath]];

[theMovie.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, (self.view.frame.size.width), (self.view.frame.size.height))];

theMovie.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
theMovie.view.tag = 9999;

[self.view addSubview:[theMovie view]];

[theMovie play];
```

The view appears, but the video doesn't start. What is wrong?

Answer (score -1):

<strike>You're passing to the `MPMoviePlayerController` an URL pointing to a m3u8 file. That is a playlist. To play media with `MPMoviePlayerController`, you have to set it an actual video file. You should parse the playlist to get the link to the real video and then init your `MPMoviePlayerController` with the real link.</strike>

Check [M3U - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) and [`MPMoviePlayerController` reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller)

Also check this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665151/mpmovieplayercontroller-m3u8-playlist/1667361#1667361)

**EDIT:** Thanks to [Hugo Silva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/819105/hugo-silva), I realized that `MPMoviePlayerController` is able to play live streams in m3u8 format, since I've not seen anything wrong in your code, I suggest you to check if it's a problem of your stream. Try using one of the [samples](http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8) provided by Apple. Also make sure that your stream meets Apple's requirements for [HTTP Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH1-DontLinkElementID_39)

Comment: But in the related question, he said that I can play a playlist file, and MPMoviePlayerController do the rest.

Comment: You're right, I'm totally wrong with this, I'm trying to find out what's wrong with your code