# how to play native m3u8 in iPhone

Tags: iphone, m3u8

when playing m3u8 palylist,it must be a remote url.My problem is : if the m3u8 index file and the ts media files are loacted in the iPhone device, then how to play by http.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1667361/1106035

Comment: what you said failed to help me

Answer (score 1):

Play  m3u8  file with WebView using load htmlString

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>HTTP Live Streaming Example</title>

</head>

<body>

    <video

        src="http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"

        height="300" width="400"

    >

    </video>

</body>

</html>
```

OR

play from mpmoviplayer just like other file